# $f(x)\to\infty, g(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, show that if $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to L$, then $\frac{\log f(x)}{\log g(x)}\to 1$, $0<L<\infty$

Tags: calculus

By L'Hospital's rule $\frac{\log f(x)}{\log g(x)}=\frac{f'(x)/f(x)}{g'(x)/g(x)}=\frac{1}{L}L=1$.
But to use L'Hospital's rule, we need $f, g$ to be differential, and limit of $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists, which didn't give by the question.
So should I stop to use L'Hospital's rule to prove the title or just the question forgot to give the necessary conditions?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{\log f(x)}{\log g(x)}=\frac{\log \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}+\log g(x)}{\log g(x)}=1+\frac{\log \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}{\log g(x)}\stackrel{x\to\infty}\longrightarrow \left[1+\frac{\log L}\infty\right]=1$

Comment: Please don't write mathematics with $1/\infty$ in it as if that were an actual real number.

Comment: @TedShifrin It's a habit I carry from back in high school, where I would put the extended real numbers arithmetics between square brackets. It's actually quite convenient, because it works as a concise exposition of an argument. For instance, this should be read as "the numerator goes to $\log L$, the denominator goes to $\infty$, therefore $1+\text{fraction}$ goes to $1$". Also, some reasonable pedmas arithmetics is possible in the extended real numbers $[-\infty,\infty]$, which works as long as one avoids $0\cdot\infty$, $0^0$, $\infty^0$, $0/0$, $\infty-\infty$ and $\pm\infty/(\pm\infty)$.

Comment: ... and division by $0$ in general, almost forgot.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\log(x)$ is continuous at $x=L$,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\log(f(x))}{\log(g(x))}-1\right)
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)}{\log(g(x))}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(L)}{\log(g(x))}\\[6pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$